# Google Play Console: Hi-res Icon: Your app icon appears to contain images or words you may not have permission to use

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

So I have the app with the following app launcher icon:

[image]

It's a simple background color and default videocam icon from Android Studio's Clip art:

[image]

I mean they themselves suggest this tool to be used by developers to generate icons.

What did I do wrong here?

Google Play has sent me the following email:

[image]

Comment: Iguess it may be similar to an already existing app, i suggest adding some details and changing colours maybe

Comment: @cmak well in this case it sounds stupid, I can not check all apps on the store, they should provide then some service to check if the icon is similar to other app's icon before first app release. Also I don't think there is patent on such icons :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue seems was with the fact that the icon is quite simple (solid bg + a standard icon) and there are already many apps with similar icon, so I decided to add linear gradient (two colors) as background and changed icon to a similar one but a random one downloaded from web, also added a transparent abbreviation of the application name to the icon (three letters) using Adobe Illustrator (mask of two objects)

Now they reviewed it and it's fine